# Regex about url encoded string

Tags: regex, url, urlencode

Would like to write one regex to get the url encoded string in below line:

```
<topicref href="%E4%BA%B0.txt"/>
```

When I used a regex like `(%[A-Z][0-9])+\.txt` it only got `%B0.txt`. What can I do if I want to get the whole url encoded string such like `%E4%BA%B0.txt`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: change it to `[%\dA-Z]+\.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Proper URL encoding uses hex digits only, `A-F` not `A-Z`. The encoded URL could contain non-encoded characters anywhere. Also, you should escape the full stop.

```
((%[0-9A-F]{2}|[^<>'" %])+)\.txt
```

is a quick ad-hoc fix for your regex, though obviously for any production code, probably don't use a regex for this at all, or at the very least try a well-defined and properly tested URL regex like the one you can find in the HTTP RFC.

Putting the `+` quantifier outside the capturing parentheses will only return the last repetition. I added a second set of parentheses to put the quantifier inside the first capture group, which assumes you are doing something to extract the first capture group in particular. (If your regex dialect has non-capturing groups, you could change the second opening parenthesis to non-capturing, i.e. `(?:`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regex to

```
([%\dA-Z]+)\.txt
```

- `([%\dA-Z]+)` - Match `%, digits and alphabets` one or more time
- `\.txt` - Match `.txt`

where as your regex means

```
(%[A-Z][0-9])+.txt
```

- `(%[A-Z][0-9])+`

  - `%` - Match `%`
  - `[A-Z]` - Match `A to Z` one time
  - `[0-9]` - Match any digit one or more time
  - `+` - Match the captured group one or more time
- `.txt` - Match `single character (anything except new line)` followed by `txt`